# Had to force computer into OS recovery

Tags: macos, imac, fusion-drive

Upon opening "Disk Utility" from the Recovery window, a prompt asks if I want to revert to a working state. How far back does a working state go? Does this mean I will lose files from my desktop?

Also, I do not see a "Macintosh HD" listing, just disk0s2 and disk1s2.

[image]

What do I do next?!

Comment: Your 1.12 TB Fusion disk "desintegrated" for unkown reason or your Fusion drive is APFS and the recovery disk system version is too old to detect it. Do you have a current backup?

Comment: No.. I haven't done a Time Machine backup :( - I try to work off of my external hard drive thankfully so whatever was on my desktop is probably lost?

Would reverting to a working state do anything?

Comment: I don't unfortunately. I can't remember if it was running Yosemite, El Capitan or Sierra

Comment: It was set to start up from the internal drive. I used the LaCie for file storage/to work off of but the internal drive ran all of my programs.

Comment: In the process of downloading El Capitan to a thumbdrive

Comment: To investigate the disks (from remote) I need access with a Remote Desktop app. A Remote Desktop app allows me to see your desktop but also use apps (e.g. Terminal.app) to further determine the reason for the  Fusion drive to break. Usually I recommend to install TeamViewer (which is free for non-commercial use). You can't install TeamViewer to a Recovery HD - a full system is required. Therefore you would have to install El Capitan to another empty drive/thumb drive (at least 16 GB/better 32 GB) configure one admin user/network etc.and d/l TeamViewer and install it.

Comment: Then you would have to send me the ID/password displayed by TeamViewer via email and then I will be able to login and examine what's wrong/maybe repair it.

Comment: The 3 dots, top left of the window would have to be Mavericks, 10.9 or earlier. That would certainly account for it not recognising an APFS disk, if indeed it is one. I'm sure it would be worth a look to see if you can get it into Internet Recovery; Cmd/Opt/R at the chimes, & see what a newer recovery might say about it.